# PROC Summary SUM returning 1 higher than it should

Tags: sas, summary, proc

So I'm running PROC SUMMARY with SUM for the frequency of something and I only have 160 observations however I am running into the issue that the sum of the frequencies is 161. I double checked the original data set that there are 160 observations and everything but something is making the frequency 161 and I'm not sure what.

I've tried some code

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE DiseaseFreq AS
    SELECT Concomitant_Disease,
            count(*) AS Freq
    FROM CAS.PreOp
    GROUP BY Concomitant_Disease;
QUIT;

DATA Disease (KEEP=var freq RENAME=var=Concomitant_Disease);
    SET DiseaseFreq;
    LENGTH var $25. freq 3.;
    DO i=1 BY 1 WHILE(SCAN(Concomitant_Disease,i,"~^,")^='');
        var=STRIP(PROPCASE(SCAN(Concomitant_Disease,i,"~^,")));
        Freq=Freq;
        OUTPUT;
    END;
RUN;

PROC SUMMARY DATA=Disease;
    CLASS Concomitant_Disease;
    VAR Freq;
    OUTPUT OUT=Count SUM=Freq;
RUN;
```

Comment: Show the log please and output from PROC SUMMARY. My guess is your data step adds another observation somehow.

Comment: why are you using "count(*) AS Freq" in proc sql and not sum(*) ? freq and sum will lead to different results

Comment: What are you referring to @Rhythm and also that entire way was pretty incorrect because I ran the code on another dataset and it didn't even product 160 or 161.

Comment: By "FREQUENCY" do you mean the number of observations in the resulting datasets?  If so then @data_null_ has given the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Tom I realize you can do data _null_ but I wanted it to grab the number of observations in the data set and place it in the code. I managed to do it with proc sql and %sqlobs.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you truncating the precision of your FREQ variable?  You told SAS to keep only three bytes of the eight bytes it takes to store a floating point number.  On Windows/Linux that is only enough bits to represent numbers as large as 8,192 exactly. Throwing away the lower order bits of precision is most likely reason why your counts are off.

Set the LENGTH for FREQ to 8.  Or just leave it alone and SAS will store all 8 bytes by default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need the NWAY option in PROC SUMMARY statement.